# SQL Query to rename multiple table prefixes not working

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I'm running this script to rename all the tables prefix in a given database, I'm doing this using MySQL Workbench, the query compiles but the talbes are not renamed, what I'm missing?

```
SET @database   = "database_name";
SET @old_prefix = "old_prefix_";
SET @new_prefix = "new_prefix_";

SELECT
    concat(
        "RENAME TABLE ",
        TABLE_NAME,
        " TO ",
        replace(TABLE_NAME, @old_prefix, @new_prefix),
        ';'
    ) AS "SQL"
FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @database;
```

I have replaced the variables accordingly to match my DB name and tables prefixes (old, new).

Comment: You're generating a string, but not executing that string - the feature you need is Dynamic SQL (https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/06/20/mysql-dynamic-sql-with-execute-and-prepare-statements/)

Comment: @NevilleKuyt but once I use the prepare/execute statement how do I loop all the talbes in the database? this SELECT statement is iterating how do I do without a SELECT statement?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html - cursor allow you to iterate over a result set. 
This is one of those "it's possible, but probably very dangerous" things...